# How to call SqlFunctions.PatIndex() with Expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have a business layer call that works like so:

```
CustomerRepository.Get(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + arg + "%", c.FirstName));
```

I am trying to build this using expressions:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Like(string LikeString, string Target)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("PatIndex");
        var arg1 = Expression.Constant(LikeString);
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "item");
        var prop = Expression.Property(item, Target);

        MethodCallExpression resultExp =
            Expression.Call(method, arg1, prop);

        var value = Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int?));

        var greaterThan = Expression.GreaterThan(resultExp, value);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(greaterThan, item);

        var result = Repo<TEntity>.Get().AsQueryable().Where(lambda);

        return result;
    }
```

When I call the above method, I get the following exception:

**`This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.`**

Any ideas of how to get past this or do what I want it to do?  Does my Expression code look ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue

from:

```
var result = Repo<TEntity>.Get().AsQueryable().Where(lambda);
```

to:

```
var result = Repo<TEntity>.Get(lambda);
```

Comment: I would also be interested to use PatIndex, could you give me a working example please? (I mean, a code snippet I could use in LinqPad). For example, what is `Repo<TEntity>`? For the community, questions are of more value, if they are reproducable. I promise, I'll upvote if you do that.

Comment: The Repo class is based on the Repository pattern commonly used with Entity Framework.  In the example used, we use this Get() method: IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

Comment: Also, that virtual method in the original question is the implementation of the Like() method in our Repository.  We have Get(), Update(), Delete(), Like() ect.  Common db functions.